# How can I use regular and bold in a single String using iText Android

Tags: android, kotlin, itext

I have a String that consists of a constant part and a variable part. I want the variable to be formatted using a regular font within the text paragraph, whereas I want the constant part to be bold.

This is my code:

```
    val boldFont = Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 22f, Font.BOLD)
    val semiBoldFont = Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16f, Font.BOLD)
    val normalFont = Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16f, Font.NORMAL)
    val lineSeparator = LineSeparator()
    lineSeparator.lineColor = BaseColor(0, 0, 0, 68)


//      NAME OF THE STUDENT
    val paragraph = Paragraph(student?.Student_Name, boldFont)
    paragraph.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER

//      DOB
    val paragraphTwo = Paragraph("Date of Birth: ", semiBoldFont)
    paragraphTwo.add(Chunk(student?.Student_DOB , normalFont))
    paragraphTwo.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER

//      Place and Country of Birth
    val paragraphThree = Paragraph("Place and Country of Birth: ", semiBoldFont)
    paragraphThree.add(Chunk(student?.Student_City + ", " + student?.Student_Country, normalFont))
    paragraphThree.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER

//      Address
    val paragraphFour = Paragraph("Address: ", semiBoldFont)
    paragraphFour.add(Chunk(student?.Student_Address + ", " + student?.Student_City + ", " + student?.Student_Country, normalFont))
    paragraphFour.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER

//      Nationality
    val paragraphFive = Paragraph("Nationality: ", normalFont)
    paragraphFive.add(Chunk(student?.Student_Nationality_One + ", " + student?.Student_Nationality_Two, normalFont))
    paragraphFive.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER

try {
        document.add(paragraph)
        document.add(Chunk(lineSeparator))
        document.add(paragraphTwo)
        document.add(paragraphThree)
        document.add(paragraphFour)
        document.add(paragraphFive)

        if (educationList.size > 0) {
            document.add(Paragraph("Education", boldFont))
            document.add(Paragraph(" "))
        }

    } catch (e: DocumentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a font in the `Paragraph` constructor, the font used for a later added `Chunk` object is the font of that chunk *supplemented by data from the paragraph font **in properties not set in the chunk font***.

The style of the font is a bit field and unfortunately this *supplementing* in the style field is implemented by means of bit-wise or-ing. Thus, the **BOLD** flag from the paragraph font is or-ed to the styles of all the chunks added to the paragraph!

You can circumvent this by not setting a font at paragraph-level at all (or at least not a font with style bits) and also adding the label as a separate chunk, e.g. instead of

```
// DOB
val paragraphTwo = Paragraph("Date of Birth: ", semiBoldFont)
paragraphTwo.add(Chunk(student?.Student_DOB , normalFont))
paragraphTwo.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER
```

do

```
// DOB
val paragraphTwo = Paragraph()
paragraphTwo.add(Chunk("Date of Birth: ", semiBoldFont))
paragraphTwo.add(Chunk(student?.Student_DOB , normalFont))
paragraphTwo.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER
```

or probably

```
// DOB
val paragraphTwo = Paragraph("", normalFont)
paragraphTwo.add(Chunk("Date of Birth: ", semiBoldFont))
paragraphTwo.add(Chunk(student?.Student_DOB , normalFont))
paragraphTwo.alignment = Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER
```

(The difference between these options is that based on the paragraph font information some spacing is added before the paragraph.)